# Get the item value of the node's parent - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use the angular material component matTree (https://stackblitz.com/angular/poxkygvnbyd?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts)

I am looking to have the item value of the parent node of a selected node. 
For exemple, when I check the node "Cook dinner", I want to write in the console the name of his parent ("Reminders").

I found a function to have the descendants of a node ( const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);) but I don't find method to get the value of the parent.

Any ideas ? 
Thanks !